# Who is this Gadol?

Tags: rishonim

The Aruch Hashulchan Orach Chaim Siman 639 Saif 16 quotes a Rashba who brings a Halacha from בשם גדול הדור מצרפת. Do we know who this Gadol is?

Comment: Try checking the footnotes of the Mosad HaRav Kook edition of the Rashba.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acc to the Bach, in that siman in the Tur on siff 5-6,  Tosafos in Brachos 49b actually names the originator of this chumra as Rabeinu Yehuda. It doesn't really look like thats what tosafos is saying though, see there d.h. ee ba'i.
Here is a side theory though. The Rosh in Brachos ch. 7 siman 23 also requires eating in the succah the first night even when it is raining. The Rosh's rebbe was Maharam of Rothenberg who has been reffered to by the grand title the Aruch Hashulchan used, the greatest Rabbi of Tsarphas. So maybe this ruling was assumed to be in the name of his rebbe? Maybe.

But untill we check the Kook edition let's go with Rabbeinu Yehuda.

Ok. After some research it turns out there is no Rashba on maseches Succah. When the Aruch Hashulchan quoted the Rashba on the sugya, he was apparently reffering to the chidushei HaRitva, a student of the Rashba, on the sugya. However, the Ritva wrote the chidush on the sugya in the name of his rebbi. He reffers to him as Mori Neru, the term he reserves for the Rashba, and not the title the Ritva calls his other rebbe the Ra'ah. This can also be proven by the fact that the Rashba has a responsa in chelek 4 siman 78 outlining this same idea. Checking in the footnote of the Kook edition Ritva you will find that they don't name who the gadol hador from tzarfas is but rather just send to the likeminded Rosh mentioned above.

The Ramma does paskin to sit in the succah the first night even in the rain. The maareh makom is given as the Trumas Hadeshen siman 95. In that tshuva we see he quotes this opinion in the name of Sma'k in the name of Rabi yuda (Rabbeinu Yehuda).

Comment: Why would the Maharam be referred to as a gadol from Tzarphat (France)? He was from Ashkenaz (Germany)!

Comment: @Noach mi Frankfurt the Rosh was from Germany. The Maharam was from Worms. Could be that was up for grabs?

Comment: Wiki says that Worms (Warmeißa in German Yiddish) was in Germany since the 1000s.

Comment: @Noach mi Frankfurt here is Wikipedia Meir of Rothenburg (c. 1215 – 1305)[1] was a German Rabbi and poet, a major author of the tosafot on Rashi's commentary on the Talmud. He is also known as Meir ben Baruch, the Maharam of Rothenburg. Rabbi Meïr ben Solomon of Perpignan, referred to Rab Meir of Rothenberg, as the "greatest Jewish leader of Zarfat" alive at the time, Zarfat is medieval Hebrew for France which was a reference to Charlemagne's rule of Germany.

Comment: Oh, so he was originally French. Sounds like parts of my family.

Comment: @Noach :) from the wiki bio it sounds like he was born in Germany, went to France to study, and ended up back in Germany.